# Fitting two semicircles in a Nyquist plot?

Tags: fourier-transform, spectroscopy, electrochemistry

I have done some impedance spectroscopy fist time recently and got the following [Nyquist plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_stability_criterion#Nyquist_plot).

Comment: What do you mean, *"design the circuit of the plot"*. Do you want to/think we can reconstruct the circuit you experimented on just from its Nyquist plot?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Actually, for passive, lossless networks with matched terminations, a Nyquist plot, if realisable by this kind of network, uniquely defines a canonical ladder network and all equivalent networks can then be classified through a certain group of affine transformations of the impedance expression. Look up the work of Wilhelm Cauer (1900 - 1945). I don't think a Cauer realisation helps the OP, but Cauer's work is thoroughly surprising, nonetheless.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimal: Very interesting indeed. If you could expand a bit on that, it would make a good answer, I think!

Comment: @ACuriousMind, These are experimental results and I need to design the circuit from the Nyquist plot. It fit well with a semicircle but I think here should be two semicircles.

Comment: @ACuriousMind and others It seems that the OP is asking a question about  a proven chemical technique, "impedance spectroscopy" (which I had not heard of) and there is a standard procedure for deriving an equivalent circuit from a semicircle. So the OP is asking for "advanced impedance spectroscopy" - what do you do when the experimental results don't fit with the standard ones (which seem to be semiscirles, as [described here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_spectroscopy) and [here](http://www.gamry.com/application-notes/basics-of-electrochemical-impedance-spectroscopy/))

Comment: Dealing with two semicircles can be done by having a pair of parallel RC circuits in series - what bothers me more is the fact that the values change with "voltage" (wherever that voltage is applied) - which suggests that resistance in the circuit is a function of voltage. We need more information about the experiment. And you should probably show you know how a "simple" Nyquist plot is created for a parallel RC circuit, and include your comment about "two semicircles" in the body of the question. If you do that I would vote to re-open.